# Cholesky Decomposition of sum of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider a positive definite matrix $A=B+C$, where $B$ and $C$ are both semi-positive definite and $Im(C)=Im(B)^{\perp}$. If $A$ has a Cholesky decomposition $A=LL^{T}$, then whether the matrix $L$ satisfies $L=Q+R$ and $QQ^{T}=B$, $RR^{T}=C$ or not?

---

My attepmt: If $L$ satisfies $L=Q+R$, then $A=QQ^{T}+QR^{T}+R^{T}Q+RR^{T}$. How can I prove whether $QR^{T}+R^{T}Q=0$ or not? I know that $Im(C)=Im(B)^{\perp}$ means $ker(B^{T})=Im(C)$, but how this condition could be used?